# Cakephp:searching with arabic text

Tags: cakephp, character-encoding

I have a problem with my website. I have French and Arabic language, and everything is working fine except the search. When I search with
text in French, I get the result, but when I put text in Arabic
language I get a Unicode character like this:

**the original text:**

[image]

**the debug result:**

[image]

**my config database.php**

```
'encoding' => 'utf8',
```

**defaut.ctp**

```
echo $this->Html->charset();
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

**my function for searching**

```
function search($query = null)
{
    $this->Activite->locale = Configure::read('Config.language');
    $query = $this->request->query['query'];
    //debug($this->request);die();
    if(isset($query))
    {
        $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 4,
            'fields' => array('Activite.*', 'Thumb.file'),
            'order' => array('Activite.created' => 'Desc'),
            'conditions' => array(
                'deleted' => false,
                'Activite.titre like' => "%$query%"
            )
        );
        $search_result = $this->paginate('Activite');
        $this->set('search_result',$search_result);

    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash("Veuillez saisir votre recherche .","flash_warning");
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'activites','action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

**Form element:**

```
<div class="right-sidebar-block">
      <h3 class="dotted_line"><?php echo __('Recherche');?></h3>
      <div class="tout">
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('Activite',array('type' => 'GET','action' => 'search')) ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('query',array('label' => false,'div' => false)); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('ok'),array('div' => false,'class' => 'myButton')); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When you are debuggig and dying that early, no charset header will be sent, so the browser will probably use the wrong encoding for display. Please debug the data in the view without dying, and check whether the browser uses the correct encoding.

Comment: i did that,i add debug from the view not from controller function,and the same problem,this is not the problem,i do debug from the controller and every thing work fine,i have a back end for adding articles with arabic text and that work very fine

Comment: when i do a debug from a view that work fine,but from the controller not working,what should do for fixing this ?